# Git Push from local repo to remote repo on a server for wordpress deployment

Tags: wordpress, git, repository, local, remote-server

Despite finding minimal consistent documentation on this topic, it is my understanding that when you push a git commit from a local repository to a remote repository on a server (my remote repository is on a bluehost server) that the files are compressed therefore, they will not be immediately visible on the server in their normal form.

One method that I successfully used to see these files "uncompressed" is to clone the repository.  I am however trying to use the local repo and remote repo in a workflow system to maintain a wordpress website.  When I push a commit from the local repo to the remote repo, I am not able to access the site through the browser.  Is there an additional step that I need to take that I am missing in order to access the uncompressed version of the files through a browser?

Do I have to clone the repository to the same folder after each push?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a website on Bluehost and this is very simple to set up. First you need to go into your CPanel and request ssh access.

Then follow this guide for setting up your private key (stays on your computer) and public key (goes in .ssh/authorized_keys on the bluehost server).

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

I setup a directory under my home directory called git and setup a test.git project. Note that I'm using ~/test as my working tree as I don't want to push files into my www. You'll use ~/www.

```
*****@******.info [~]# 
*****@******.info [~/git]# mkdir test.git
*****@******.info [~/git]# cd test.git
*****@******.info [~/git/test.git]# pwd
/home1/******/git/test.git
*****@******.info [~/git/test.git]# git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /home1/*******/git/test.git/
*****@******.info [~/www/test.git]# cd hooks
*****@******.info [~/www/test.git]# vi post-receive
```

The post-receive file:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home1/*******/test git checkout -f
```

Save the file with :x

```
*****@******.info [~/www/test.git/hooks]# chmod +x post-receive
*****@******.info [~/www/test.git/hooks]# cd ~
*****@******.infoo [~]# git init test
Initialized empty Git repository in /home1/*******/test/.git/
*****@******.info [~]# exit
```

Back on my local machine:

```
[nedwidek@yule ~]$ git init test.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/nedwidek/test.git/.git/
[nedwidek@yule ~]$ cd test.git
[nedwidek@yule test.git]$ touch testfile.txt
[nedwidek@yule test.git]$ git add .
[nedwidek@yule test.git]$ git commit -m "testing" .
[master (root-commit) 1d6697c] testing
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 testfile.txt
[nedwidek@yule test.git]$ git remote add origin *****@******.info:/home1/*****/git/test.git
[nedwidek@yule test.git]$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 270 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To *****@******.info:/home1/*******/test.git
   f144186..0fd10f8  master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

I checked and testfile.txt was placed in ~/test/.

Comment: If your local machine is windows, you'll want to install the full PuTTY distribution and setup pageant to manage your keys. Then you can use TortoiseGIT as your git client.

Comment: The Git_Work_Tree has to point to a different location than the repository?

Comment: Yes, the repository is different than a working tree. It won't actually look like a local git repository (no files except git files). In this case your working tree is your www directory (or where ever you need the copy of the files when you do a git push from your local machine.

Comment: I'd show you what was in mine, but I deleted it after I posted these instructions.

Comment: great, detailed answer but I'm curious if this is this the best practice for git workflow with multiple developers? I  have heard you should be cloning the repository on the server and then pulling into it from the production remote, rather than pushing up to it. I believe this also allows you to control the merge on the server rather than pushing and having no control of how the files will merge afterwards

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to this much, much earlier. I would agree that this is only suitable for a single developer situation or a situation in which you need to make things available to other users outside of git (At IBM we occasionally used this mirroring setup in multi-dev environments where the code needed to be looked at from another tool). I would also agree that this is only good for a test server. Production should only ever be updated with pre-announced downtimes and great care.