# Publish a site to a remote server from a local Git repository

Tags: php, git, github, ssh

The plan is to publish a site on the hosting server from a Git repository that I created on my local machine.

I created a Git repository in my server:

```
git init
```

Then I added a remote in my local to be able to upload the site:

> git remote add origin ssh:com1@*************/home/com1/public_html/aum-crm/aum-crm.git

And I was able to push the site using `git push origin master`. The problem is that after the site got pushed, I have to go to the server and do two steps.

```
 Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   some/files/got_here.php
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
```

I then do this:

```
git reset HEAD .
```

which results in this:

```
Unstaged changes after reset:
M        some/files/got_here.php
```

Finally I do `git checkout --`, and then the server will have the files.

If I tried to commit on the server instead of these step, but then it reverts which means it cancels all the files that got submitted from the local. :(

Why do I need to do these two steps? Isn't it supposed to just push the files to the server and they have to go there right away?

Comment: I think you can at least replace your two remote commands with `git pull`, which will be quicker to do. However if you look into post-commit hook scripts, you should find a way to do this completely automatically.

Comment: Could you please explain how, I am not an expert in git yet.

Comment: Incidentally, I use a similar approach, but I have two repos on my remote server. One is a bare repo, which is the remote I push to, and the other is the live site, which uses the bare repo as a remote. I can then do `git pull` in live, which retrieves the latest copy from the bare repo.

Comment: I don't know how to do commit hooks, though I expect I could after 15 minutes with a search engine! Use my suggestion as a tip for your ongoing research, rather than a full solution - it's probably been written down several thousand times already. I'd start by searching for "git post commit hook Linux".

Answer (score 0):

```
*****@******.info [~]# 
*****@******.info [~/git]# mkdir test.git
*****@******.info [~/git]# cd test.git
*****@******.info [~/git/test.git]# pwd
/home1/******/git/test.git
*****@******.info [~/git/test.git]# git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /home1/*******/git/test.git/
*****@******.info [~/www/test.git]# cd hooks
*****@******.info [~/www/test.git]# vi post-receive
```

The post-receive file:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home1/*******/test git checkout -f
```

Save the file with :x

```
*****@******.info [~/www/test.git/hooks]# chmod +x post-receive
*****@******.info [~/www/test.git/hooks]# cd ~
*****@******.infoo [~]# git init test
Initialized empty Git repository in /home1/*******/test/.git/
*****@******.info [~]# exit
```

This way it's going to make the server do these steps automatically.

Thanks to [Erik Nidwidek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63386/erik-nedwidek).

[Link to his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16678439/2909855)